# Weird resistor patterns

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I came up with the following question:

> The vertices of tetrahedron ABCD are all connected by 1-ohm resistors. What is the total resistance between A and B?

I haven't the faintest idea how to solve it. Does it involve infinite path summations at some point?

[edit: how about from A to C?]

Comment: What's the definition of "total resistance"?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! This question might find a new home at electric engineering?

Comment: @StefanBischof topically yes, but they've told me they don't take no-effort homework questions either.

Comment: ... why is it put on hold as off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry, C and D are at the same potential.  You can merge them to one point, called CD.  Then A to CD is $\frac 12 \Omega$, as is CD to B.  You have two parallel $1 \Omega$ resistors, so the total is $\frac 12 \Omega$

Comment: How can C and D be at the same potential if there is a resistor between them?

Comment: @LDC3 Wheatstone bridge : ever heard of it?

Comment: @LDC3 What does this condition imply about the current? So it's as though the said resistor isn't there.

Comment: ABCD goes around the outside of the figure, not ACBD as you think it does. Where does it say a wheatstone bridge? It says tetrahedron.

Comment: @LDC3 If you connect 2 points at same potential with a resistor, will they cease to be at the same potential?

Comment: @Awesome, I don't think we are talking about the same layout. What is stated is 4 resistors are connected in a tetrahedron. There are no other connections and A and B are separated by one 1-ohm resistor. If there is a potential between A and B, then there is a potential between A and D, D and C and C and B.

Answer (score -1):

Ross Millikan got you half the way there. The effective 1/2 ohm path through CD is also in parallel with the direct AB resistor, so the total resistance is 1/3 ohm.

Comment: Forgot CD to B to be in series with that 1/2?

Answer (score -1):

I think everyone forgot how to do this:

$\frac {1}{R_{eff}} = \frac {1}{R1} + \frac{1}{R2} + ...$

$\frac {1}{R_{eff}} = \frac {1}{1} + \frac{1}{3}$

$\frac {1}{R_{eff}} = \frac {4}{3}$

$R_{eff} =$ 0.75 ohms

Comment: I don't follow this answer. Could you please explain it more?

Comment: You have serious misconceptions about words series and parallel.

Comment: OK, I took a short cut. We have two parallel paths, one path is one 1-ohm resister and the other path is three 1-ohm resistors. So the 2 parallel paths are 1/1 + 1/3, which is what I have above.

Comment: Well, there is ACB also. You can either apply symmetry or kirchoff's laws